# use “OR” in *ngIf

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have a response coming from an API, and I would like to set an if condition to check if the response is 3 or 6 to set the ng-template to success else any other data gotten should be set to danger,

How do I check if the data.delivery_status is 3 or 6 ?

This is my code below which does not work:

```
<li *ngIf="data.delivery_status==='3' OR '6';then success else danger"></li>
<ng-template #success>
    <td><span class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Sent</span></td>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #danger>
    <td><span class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Sent</span></td>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: use `&&` for `AND` , `||` for `OR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `*ngIf="data.delivery_status==='3' || data.delivery_status === '6'` instead of `OR '6'`

```
<li *ngIf="data.delivery_status==='3' || data.delivery_status === '6';then success else danger"></li>
<ng-template #success>
    <td><span class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Sent</span></td>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #danger>
    <td><span class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Sent</span></td>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do like below

```
*ngIf="(data.delivery_status === 3 || data.delivery_status === 6);then success else danger"
```

**Full code**

```
<li *ngIf="(data.delivery_status === 3 || data.delivery_status === 6);then success else danger"></li>
<ng-template #success>
  <td><span class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Sent - success</span></td>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #danger>
  <td><span class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Sent - danger</span></td>
</ng-template>
```

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hsddvl)

Answer (score 2):

Since the options are mutually exclusive, just add the `li` element twice with both variations:

```
<li *ngIf="data.delivery_status==='3'">
    <ng-template #success>
        <td><span class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Sent</span></td>
    </ng-template>
</li>

<li *ngIf="data.delivery_status==='6'">
<ng-template #danger>
    <td><span class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Sent</span></td>
</ng-template>
</li>
```

Angular will render only one of them, depending on the value of `delivery_status`.

Comment: This renders success for 3 and danger for 6 which is not what the author wanted. The author wants to render success for 3 and 6 and danger otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

`<li *ngIf="data.delivery_status==='3' || data.delivery_status==='6';then success else danger"></li>`

but better is to extract that condition into the component.

Answer (score 0):

use below code for OR condition

```
<li *ngIf="data.delivery_status ==='3' || data.delivery_status === '6';then success else danger"></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you want `success` when status is '3' OR '6', but all other cases are `danger`. So here is my code:

```
<li *ngIf="data.delivery_status==='3' || data.delivery_status==='6'">
    <td><span class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Sentt - success</span></td>
</li>
<li *ngIf="!(data.delivery_status==='3' || data.delivery_status==='6')">
    <td><span class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Sent - danger</span></td>
</li>
```

It's also a good opportunity to use NgSwitch.

> See: https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch

Here is my coding suggestion:

```
 <li [ngSwitch]="data.delivery_status">
     <td *ngSwitchCase="'3'"><span class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Sentt - success</span></td>
     <td *ngSwitchCase="'6'"><span class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Sentt - success</span></td>
     <td *ngSwitchDefault><span class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Sent - danger</span></td>
 </li>
```